# DB2: Is it good to create the LONG table space to use 32 KB data page

Tags: db2, tablespaces, db2-luw, data-pages

Our DB2 database (V9.7) has only defined one table space to store all the big objects like XML.
And xml size could be different. Some are about 2kb average. And some are 7kb average.
So does it make sense to set the table space to use 32kb data page?
How to judge it? I have once seen that one data page can only contain one xml row.
Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the general answer I gave to you on your [other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22526/db2-is-it-good-to-create-the-index-table-space-to-use-32-kb-data-page/22545#22545).

If you are storing your XML as a LOB, then I guess I'd see what is the common average size per table. If the average size is 4MB or less (which it sounds like), then you'd only need a 4K tablespace (see [Space requirements for table](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0052385.html), table 1).

If you are storing the XML as an XML data type in DB2, then you actually get some performance gains over LOB, especially if you inline the XML (and aren't doing updates to it all that often). This may be the best since you mention sizes less than 32K. You may wish to check out [XML storage](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0050646.html) page for in-lining XML within the table vs outside for XML storage.

Comment: I am a bit hesitating to use inline to store the xml into the base table directly. As it said, it will be benefit to operate on the xml. But not normally it happens on non-xml columns.And the base table is defined on the table space with 4k data page. I could try to inline some small xml column though.